# Why does this question show as "marked as duplicate by Community♦"?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, community-user

I erroneously flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972955/convert-json-to-genericlist-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment46197451_28972955) as duplicate.

While I was searching how to undo that, I noticed the question became closed as duplicate, but *singlehandedly by community* with no other user names listed, such as myself.

> marked as duplicate by Community♦ 11 hours ago

What does that mean? And why did it happen? Can I still remove the duplicate flag?

Comment: It seems that it is too easy for the OP to agree to the duplicate vote; I just helped to reopen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971738/printing-the-name-of-a-variable) after the OP agreed to a wrong dupe vote there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "That solved my problem!" button do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300364/what-does-the-that-solved-my-problem-button-do)

Answer (score 76):

This is [a relatively new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/175248), in which the OP has the ability to agree with a duplicate close vote.

If they do, the question is then closed immediately by Community.

Given that the user actually *agreed* with the duplicate, I don't see the need to revert your flag.  Of course, if you or others feel that it was in error, then you're welcome to cast a reopen vote.  It'll make its way through the reopen queue, where a few others will hopefully agree with your reopen vote.

Comment: I believe the OP may have done that in error or frustration. The duplicate is clearly the opposite of what they were asking for. I voted to reopen. (not that it's a particularly great question anyway).

Comment: You've done your part, then.  It'll make its way back into the reopen queue, and hopefully be reopened.

Comment: It was my mistake to mark it as duplicate in the first place, as @MattBurland said. unfortunately I believe I can't cast a reopen vote yet.

Comment: Btw, this was also posted as a [separate discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes).

Comment: from now, gold badge owners can always leave that original question, and add a more accurate one using the "edit" feature to add more than 1 original question, making the links more complete.