# What does the "That solved my problem!" button do?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

Why does this button appear? Because someone's suggested this is a duplicate?

What happens when I click this button? Will my question be closed? Will score from the guys who've already answered my question be retracted?

[image: example image]

Comment: _"Will my question be closed?"_ Yes. _"Will score from the guys who've already answered my question be retracted?"_ No.

Comment: See the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981) on MSE.

Comment: See also: [Why does this question show as marked duplicate by community?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287763/why-does-this-question-show-as-marked-duplicate-by-community)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Correct, this button appears because your question has attracted at least one close vote for being a duplicate of existing question.

If you click on the button, you'll see a confirmation box. On confirmation, the question will be closed instantly. Everyone will retain the reputation earned for that question and its answers, however no new answers will be allowed to be posted.

Comment: Also, the close banner has "marked as duplicate by Community".  And the hover text for Community says: "This question's author approved a pending duplicate vote"

Comment: @ryanyuyu Wouldn’t it be actually better if the OP appeared as user voted to close?

Comment: @idmean your suggestion has been discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250960/). Shog9♦ stated this in [comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes#comment819394_250960): `question owners do not have binding close votes on their own post .... The system is closing the question, not the user who confirmed the duplicate.`