# Flag duplicate question to be marked as duplicate of different question

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, declined-flags

I want a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410609/class-fornameoracle-jdbc-diver-oracledriver), which is marked as duplicate of A, to link to B instead. As it is already marked as duplicate, the only remaining flags allowed are `spam`, `rude or abusive` and `in need of moderator attention`.

So I decided to go with the latter option and notify a moderator about this question, as it is *obviously* linked to a totally unrelated answer. A better matching link is provided in the comments. However my flag was declined with "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention".

My question is: Is there a way I can (flag to) change the duplicate's link? If not wouldn't that mean, that moderation intervention *is* required?

Comment: What do you mean *"change the link target"*? If you actually mean close the question as a duplicate of a *different* question than the one it is currently closed as a duplicate of, it will need to be re-opened and closed again. However, that seems like a lot of effort for a question that should clearly just be deleted. Also, as it's closed by Community, that means that the OP *accepted nathanchere's suggestion* (see e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300364/3001761). Why they would do that, I do not know!

Comment: I rephrased my question. Reopening and closing again seems a little over the top, indeed.

Comment: The problem is solved....

Comment: I found a similar question, and couldn't see anyway to flag it, so posted in meta. (Where I was frustrated, because my suggestion got rejected, and I felt like the moderators had missed my point: reading your question I now understand a bit better, as it sounds like changing the "duplicate link" is not the trivial operation it ought to be, but involves re-opening and closing again!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your moderator flag was declined because this is something that can be dealt with in the normal way by the community at large - it doesn't need a moderator's exception-handling powers to fix. I would say that, in cases like this, you have four options:

1. **Vote to reopen** - if it's not actually a duplicate of the question that it's currently closed as a duplicate of, perhaps it should be reopened? You can always leave a comment proposing the alternative duplicate, so that if it does get reopened the process can start over;
2. **Get A. N. Otheruser to fix it** - someone with a gold badge in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) could reopen and re-dupe it unilaterally, so perhaps you can enlist some help from the Java chat room to sort this out;
3. **Do nothing** - the post was ultimately closed by Community, which means that the OP actually *accepted* the proposed duplicate question as solving their problem (as unbelievable as that seems, given that it clearly doesn't...); or
4. **Vote to delete** - that question is very low quality, had the OP spent any time researching they would never have needed to ask it, and wasting any further time on it seems pointless.

*For users with <10k rep.: I and two other users chose option 4, so this particular example is no longer a problem...*

Comment: Didn't know there were permissions based on badges (instead of reputation). So any gold badge in one of the tags of the questions would work for option 2?

Comment: @SebastianS just for identifying duplicates, nothing else - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/248731

Comment: @SebastianS and yes, any of the tags, but [tag:jdbc] only has [one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1428/jdbc) gold-badged user, vs. [332](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/java) for [tag:java].

Comment: SO really lacks an effective channel to get this resolved. I have no way to make sure my request doesn't get drown out in the messages in chat before it reaches someone who can handle. Vote to delete is a good solution for many of theses cases, but it requires 10k and at least 2 other people.

Comment: That's ridiculous. Getting results through non-mod channels would be cumbersome and uncertain, whereas a moderator could handle it quickly and easily. Why discourage this flagging behavior?

Comment: There is low chance of getting this sort of thing resolved the "normal way". The close and reopen review systems just do not work that well.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the gold-badge-users in the chat room. They're the experts (moderators are not)

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude moderators *can't* handle "this is not a *good* duplicate" requests because they are not experts in all possible tags on StackOverflow. Generally getting post linked on META resolves issues pretty quickly - not sure why you claim moderators (imagining if they allow such low priority flags to be ok) would take less time to handle all "don't like this dup request" flags. Feel free to search through questions on META complaining that flags are not handled in weeks (due priority of flags)...