# Why was this post marked as duplicate by the asker (who does not have close privilege) AND Community?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, community-user

When a duplicate is suggested and the OP clicks on the ["That solved my problem!" button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300364/what-does-the-that-solved-my-problem-button-do), the post will be closed as a duplicate and the [close banner will read marked as duplicate by Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300364/what-does-the-that-solved-my-problem-button-do#comment226678_300366).

Why does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54950363/updated-script-from-py-file-while-importing-to-jupyter-notebook-python-3-6) show as marked as duplicate by the poster AND Community?

Also, how did they close it with multiple dupe targets?

**Edit**: This [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250960) and the comments underneath seem to indicate that this shouldn't happen since [*"users without close privilege can't really vote to close"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes#comment819206_250960) and [*"The system is closing the question, not the user who confirmed the duplicate"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes#comment819394_250960).

Comment: They probably flagged their question as duplicate of one of the two links, whereas the initial closer gave another one

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier admittedly I don't remember how closing your own question worked before getting voting privileges (at 3000 rep) but this seems odd. I wasn't aware that a user can simultaneously flag their question as a duplicate AND accept a different suggested duplicate target. As far as I remember, this is the first time I've seen it happen like this.

Comment: I don't think they accepted the other one. My big flail in the dark here is 1. user flagged as duped 2. OP flagged as another dupe 3. community closed as dupe because OP flagged 4. all dupes concerned are marked on the question

Comment: Interesting. Doesn't seem to be anything to worry about here, though. Are you saying there's a problem, or are you just curious?

Comment: @JoshCaswell just curious. I didn't initially think there was a problem, but after reading [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes) perhaps there's a bug here?

Comment: Yeah, it's possible.

Comment: No bug. Working as designed. Updated Laurel's answer to make clear it isn't just speculation.

Comment: This can also be done to voluntarily close one's own post as a duplicate when no one has proposed it as a target: vote to close yourself then approve the vote.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

At [250 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes), everyone gets the privilege of voting to close their own questions.

What happened is, one user (pault) voted to close the question as a duplicate of [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module). Then, there was some discussion in the comments, and pault suggested a different question: [How to reload a module's function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271082/how-to-reload-a-modules-function-in-python). The OP (Antonio López Ruiz) voted to close his own question as a duplicate of that one, which was done with the help of Community (who has moderator privileges).

[All duplicate targets are listed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278991/323179) in the banner when a question is closed as a duplicate. This list of duplicate targets is also [editable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links) by gold tag badge holders.