# Incorrect dupe hammer by Community

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

This question [CSS image is not loading in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49814339/css-image-is-not-loading-in-html5) was closed as a duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) by [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

After reading [Why does this question show as “marked as duplicate by Community♦”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287763/why-does-this-question-show-as-marked-as-duplicate-by-community) it would appear that a user suggested a duplicate and OP accepted this suggestion.

However, the two questions are clearly not related other than sharing the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag.

OPs comments suggest that this question should actually be closed as "No longer reproducible. Typo error". It was an incorrect file path.

What should be done about this if anything?

**Should I vote to re-open in the hope that the question is then re-closed for the correct reason?** I don't particularly want this question to be re-opened as it is likely to attract incorrect answers from people who don't read the comments.

**Should I flag it?** I don't want to unnecessarily give the mods extra work.

**Should I do nothing and get on with my life?** Tempting.

Comment: If it needs to be closed anyway I wouldn't bother. The only maybe negative side-effect is that it might act as a wrong signal-post.

Comment: My concern with incorrect dupes is that they have the potential to lead beginners down a rabbit hole of wrong leads when they perhaps should be looking somewhere else entirely.

Comment: If its a typo, it probably needs to be deleted/will be deleted.

Comment: It can't be deleted because it is marked as a duplicate. Or at least _I_ can't vote for deletion. This would have been my first action if the option was available. @SurajRao

Comment: It can't be deleted because its score is too high but I don't want to be accused of being a voting mob organizer ...

Comment: I've re-opened it as Gold Badge holder (which has also removed the Dupe vote). I'd suggest we let nature take it's course.

Comment: Unfotuntely, I cannot RE-vote to close as I already VTC as a typo.

Comment: ...and Boltclock has hammered it! Problem solved :)

Comment: I don't think you can vote to close once you've voted to reopen.

Comment: @shmosel Incorrect. You can only vote to close once, period. Reopens work the same way, IIRC

Comment: don't reopen. If you have a gold badge, you can change the duplicate target. Or suggest a gold badge owner to do that (SOCVR is a good place for this)

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre: You need to reopen to change from "duplicate" to a different close reason.

Comment: Just to note: Community only duplicate closes a post when the *post author confirm a suggested dupe*

Comment: …and the question has been deleted.

Comment: @Paulie_D: You can edit the dup list instead of reopen / close.  (I think dup-list edits are only available if you have a gold badge in one of the tags).  Anway, that lets you fix the dup target even if you don't have a close-vote left on that question.