# Could we distinguish between the "Community" closer and the "Asker" when they accept suggested closure?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Ask a question that will be closed as a duplicate
- Accept that duplicate

**Problem:**

When looking for example at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51104486/8041231) closure information, it confuses me (as a visitor). I see that Tom Brunberg suggested to close that question as a duplicate, but what happened next?

[image]

Could we change the final closure "Community" user closer to the "Asker" user?

Comment: Perhaps a decent alternative would be to emphasize "The question's author approved a pending duplicate vote." from the hover tooltip into a more prominent place.

Answer (score 2):

The user *generally* doesn't have the power to close their own question, as that power is reserved by users who have enough reputation to close questions, or by moderators.

The Community user is a moderator, and has the power to close questions, and since the OP would be the one requesting the action (and they cannot perform it), then the Community user would need to own the closure action.

The Community user itself owns quite a lot in terms of votes - [you can see that](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) on their profile page.

---

For elaboration (and some technical detail):

The only people who can cast binding close votes are diamond moderators and gold badge users in a given tag, and only then in the case of a duplicate vote.  Since the OP in this does not have a gold badge for *any* tag, and because they are not a diamond moderator, they only have a non-binding close vote.

It used to be the case that an OP vote was the same as anyone else's vote on a duplicate, but that is effectively worked around by the fact that Community *is* a diamond moderator *and* can cast a binding vote on a post.  This was implemented [back in 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287764/1079354), and was intended to help OPs more effectively moderate their own content.

Comment: I meant that "most probably" happened that the user Tom Brunberg suggested the question to be closed as a duplicate with another one and the OP accepted that (as for what we cannot see it was the OP but the "Community" user). I don't know, there was some way to show timeline of a post, could you suggest me how?

Comment: @Victoria:  The OP themselves did not close the question.  They voted for it to be closed.  The system picked that up and closed it on their behalf, so the closure *shouldn't* be attributed to the OP.

Comment: @Victoria:  If you enter in https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51104486/timeline, you'll be able to see the exact timeline of the post.

Comment: Why? If I ask a question and you mark it as a duplicate and I accept that, I would like to know the others to know what I did. (ah, timeline was that, thank you!)

Comment: @Victoria If you mouse over the "Community" link, it will say "This question's author approved a pending duplicate vote."

Comment: @gparyani, aha, you're right (good point!). Although, I'm an "inpatient newcomer" seeing such question for the first time.