# Include OP's name when they agree community's suggestion to close as duplicate (per my sole VTC)?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, community-user

I was the only one who cast a VTC on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740328/select-case-is-working-with-one-condition-but-i-want-it-for-two), and then it was promptly closed by community. I just learned from here:

[Why does this question show as “marked as duplicate by Community♦”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287764/8112776)

...that when a question get a VTC as Duplicate, the OP is asked if they want to close it (even if there's only one vote).

If the OP accepts, the question is closed:

[image]

My question/suggestion is, could the OP's username also be included in the list on the notice, or some other way of marking it to **clearly indicate that *"even the OP"*** believes their question is duplicate?

Perhaps more importantly, does *Community* also **advise the OP that immediate *deletion* is also an option**?

Comment: "The asker is **not** closing the question. They're not closing it unilaterally, they're not closing it with [Community](/users/-1)'s help, they're not casting a binding vote or exercising any special privilege. **They are answering a question posed by the system, and the system may close their question based on their response.** I know this seems like splitting hairs, but... It's a pretty important distinction..." ([Change how questions marked as duplicates by the asker are represented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259381/165773))

Comment: @gnat: That's still a dumb distinction. You could just as easily argue that I'm not closing a question when I perform a hammer-close; I'm sending an HTTP request, and the system closes the question based on my request.

Comment: Even with that distinction in mind, maybe there is a way to make the already existing tooltip stating "This question's author approved a pending duplicate vote" a _bit_ more obvious? I just needed to read two linked questions to even recognize there was a tooltip at all.

Comment: @user2357112 well yeah until recently clarification I quoted and referred above didn't look compelling to me either. However yesterday discussion in comments over there managed to spark [a bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259379/change-how-questions-marked-as-duplicates-by-the-asker-are-represented/259381#comment1037286_259381) that sort of convinced me, that when we say someone closes we have to assume they also can reopen, which is not quite the case here (nor I would want it to be the case). I still feel that wording here needs to be improved but it got trickier than I thought

Comment: Just a passing comment that *tooltips are an awful place to put any important information* if there is no obvious reason for a user to hover their mouse there. Maybe an obvious "?" or "more info" link could trigger a proper popup linking to a help page?

Comment: @gnat I would call that an implementation detail that should be hidden from the user, to avoid confusing the issue.