# Shouldn't the question asker's duplicate close vote be authoritative?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

I asked [a question that was a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134813/dom-clientwidth-maximum-value?noredirect=1#comment97010618_55134813). A commenter noted it was possibly a duplicate. I agreed and clicked to close it. The result was that my vote to close was recorded.

As the question asker, shouldn't my opinion that the question is a duplicate be just as authoritative as my opinion that the question has been answered? I could delete the question, but I believe that my question will be hit with different search terms, so it is arguably useful to have.

Note, I clicked the "close" button, and didn't click "yes" on "extra info" as fbueckert suggests and Servy assumes I did.

Indeed, I don't see any "extra info" which invites me to respond -- perhaps a bug?

---

> [image: OP's view of the unclosed question with banner pointing to possible duplicate]

---

Makoto suggests that this is either a bug, or that I didn't click "close". In fact, my close vote has been recorded, so a bug?:

---

> [image: Close vote dialog with header "You have already voted to close this question"]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287763/why-does-this-question-show-as-marked-as-duplicate-by-community

Comment: Hmm... @Servy links to another discussion about this that seems to be inconclusive. So why is this meta question attracting downvotes? Is it phrased badly? The discussion there didn't seem to cover the OP's perspective.

Comment: Did you vote to close, or did you click, "Yes" on the extra info box that shows up after someone votes to close as a duplicate.  The former just uses your vote, while the latter allows Community to binding close vote it.

Comment: I clicked "close". As a UI choice the separation of these features seems problematic -- especially as there is no contextual information. If it is intended to give the OP a choice, there should be an extra dialog asking whether they want to vote or just close.

Comment: @shaunc What is "inconclusive" about the question.  It's quite definitive in what it states.

Comment: That would explain it.  You, yourself, don't have a binding vote, not even on your own questions; could you imagine the chaos new users would sow with thinking their question should be closed when they get their answer?  You can empower Community to do it for you by confirming it was a duplicate.  There is an argument to be made that voting to close as duplicate after the first one should confirm it, though.

Comment: As a UI choice why should a button marked "close" be a vote, while buttons marked "edit" or "delete" not be votes without explanation?

Comment: You could argue that the poster doesn't have the needed knowledge to decide if it should be closed or not, even more so if it is a poster who is new to the site.

Comment: @servy -- fbueckert explains your linked question is in regard to different functionality. Indeed I still don't see where the "extra info box" appears, and don't understand why I'm getting downvotes even when community seems like it wants to discuss.

Comment: If you clicked "close", the post should've been closed by the Community user.  The fact that you *didn't* get that indicates one of two things - either you *really* didn't hit close [since I can't find it in the post history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55134813/timeline), or there actually is a UI bug.  Do you see exactly what's in the picture *right now* on that question?

Comment: @Makoto -- see image -- definitely voted to close.

Comment: @Makoto Are you sure that the user voting to close their own question as a dupe triggers the community closure?  [Shog's specs on the feature don't seem to mention that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/193762)

Comment: I suppose I should quantify this - if the user decides to close the question through the UI, then it should be closed by them and the Community user.  If they close it through the normal close vote flow, I don't think it works the same.  Perhaps it *should*, which would still lead me to believe that this could be a bug.

Comment: @fbueckert - As pic shows, my close vote as been recorded. Makoto is right that my vote doesn't appear in the history.

Comment: I'm not seeing it; I suspect due to my inability to vote to close, the timeline also hides pending close vote history items.

Comment: @fbueckert -- hmm... what is a "pending close vote" -- that is, why would a close vote be marked as pending? Perhaps what has happened is that my close vote wasn't "definitive" somehow?

Comment: Pending as in, you've voted, but you don't have enough votes yet to close.

Comment: @fbueckert -- thanks. I see the other close vote is not on the timeline either (just the comment that it was a duplicate).

Comment: @yivi's answer (since deleted) seemed more or less to summarize. My hypothesis is that I am not getting the "extra info" that would ask if I accepted close as duplicate designation, as the number of close votes hasn't crossed some threshold. So might not be a bug :) but still is a confusing UI.

Comment: @JoeW -- you could also say that a user might not know whether their question was answered or not, yet even new users can mark a question as answered. I don't see that recognizing a duplicate is significantly more challenging than recognizing an answer.

Comment: They can select an answer but we can't be sure that it is a correct or the best answer. And close voting is a privilege that is earned. It could be they close a question as a duplicate when it should be closed for another reason.

Comment: @JoeW ... hmm; ok. But they could delete it, right? I'm not sure if you aren't thinking from the perspective of the existing rules ("close voting is a privilege that is earned"), rather than standing back and thinking about what is reasonable from a user perspective. If someone else strongly feels that the question is not a duplicate (and is an important question), then couldn't they simply ask it again? Maybe a better feature would be to allow another user to "take over" if original user disowns it and reopen as their own question.

Comment: In summary, the *purpose* of closing as duplicate is so that people don't waste their time ("DRY"). I hypothesize that it is more important than maintenance of privilege or edge cases in which users close for the wrong reason.

Comment: for me there is no repeated question, instead we should talk of repeated answer. A question is bind to a given author and , on the other side, an answer is related to the nature or topic that the question aims to. From that perspective ownards the question shall be not closed for having an existing answer that also fullfils the same question. Maybe that perspective could improve how we handle, as a community, the duplicated material without beign "hard" with anyone.

Comment: Related on MSE: [Grant the OP a binding close as duplicate vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172002) which was closed as a dupe of [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981), which got the same feedback as your suggestion.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Maybe not really a bug per se, but confusing UI. (Which **could** be construed to be a bug, but I'm not getting there).

Users do not have binding close-votes for their own posts. That's the reason the Community user closes the question for the user if they "accept" the duplicate suggestion. Community has binding votes, among many other bot-powers.

But you didn't accept the dupe-suggestion. You voted to close directly, which correctly recorded your vote. (And you could cast a close vote since [when you are over 250 rep you are able to cast close votes on your own posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)).

Maybe if you are voting to close your own post, and you are choosing a dupe-target already identified by an existing close vote, the Community user could intervene as if you had accepted the dupe suggestion directly.

I'm not sure if I'd classify this as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), it depends on the on how the original feature was *intended* to work.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a bug necessarily. Keep in mind that if the author accepts a duplicate, those targets proposed by <3k users casting recommend closure flags are also included; an author may not want to include one of those, and by avoiding using the button, only those targets selected by voters (not flaggers) will show in the list.