# Silver badge close-superpowers?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I haven't been active here for nearly a year, so I might have missed on a change, but do silver tag badge holders have the power to singlehandedly close answers as duplicate?

I ask because I came across this:
[image]

The user only has a silver badge in the relevant tag, but I'm also not quite sure what Community's role is here.

Comment: Probably closed their own question?

Comment: probably this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287763/why-does-this-question-show-as-marked-as-duplicate-by-community

Comment: It helps a bit if we see the timeline: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61937741/timeline

Comment: @rene: That's probably it. Shame, the newer Q/A was better than the old one, though I'm not entirely unbiased here :). Where'd you find that timeline?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316).

Comment: he voted to, close his own question because it was a dupe, and a moderator closed it then. No super powers needed

Comment: @nbk No moderator was involved in closing that question. Read the duplicate.

Comment: Coummnity is a User who has moderator rights, i am not sure, if it is **only** an automatic change program  or if moderators also use it to not be retaliated, some times the changes come to deliberate for an automate